# Find lost Samsung Galaxy Ace phone?

Tags: gps, lost-phone

3 weeks ago I lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace. I don't have any tracker applications or any "if lost" applications installed. I'm looking for some tracker that doesn't need a sim card, just a locator using gps locator, but I also don't have any IMEI number or even email.
So please help me, is there any way to find my lost Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830?

Comment: Do you know anything about your phone?

Comment: I'd say after 3 weeks, I know one thing about that phone: The battery is probably empty, so the only thing to detect the device might be a metal detector. Except, of course, somebody found it and charged it. But as there's no SIM card in it, and also no IMEI etc -- maybe the battery is missing as well...

Comment: This won't help you now, but Lookout recently added a feature where it will record the geocoordinates of your device if the battery is about to go dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up your Google Account on it, your only hope is probably [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb).

> Plan B is the 'find my phone' app that you download AFTER you lose your phone.
>   Plan B is your last resort to find your missing phone.
>
> This is the first and only 'find my phone' app that you download AFTER you've already lost your phone. Having Lookout on your phone is the best way to protect your phone and find it fast, but use Plan B if you have already lost your phone and didn't have Lookout installed.