# Lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos. No app Installed. Sim also not working. Can anyone help how to trace it

Tags: lost-phone

Lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos. No app Installed. Sim also not working. Can anyone plz help how to trace it.

Comment: Chandan, I just added the `lost-phone` tag to your question. Please click it and check the other 17 questions using it. At least one of them should give you initial help. Closest match: [Find lost Samsung Galaxy Ace phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30541/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way for you to trace it when all wireless options are nill. The best that you can do is to report the IMEI of the phone to your network so they can block it, becoming only a useless brick.

I don't know if some network operator have the ability to track phones thru IMEI. You should ask them, its worth a try.

edit: I think my thinking went overboard about your case. Have you simply lost it in the house or a familiar place?